# GitHub: Viewer-react-express-headless

Tags: git, heroku, github, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I forked my own *viewer-react-express-headless* (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless) and edited the *credentials.js* and Deployed to Heroku.

Here is my result: https://limitless-wave-headless.herokuapp.com/

It doesnt seem like it's quite working. Neither of the models loads. I did try to change the URN for one of the six existing models here: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless/blob/master/src/components/Gallery/Gallery.js - but none of them still loads. What could be the problems?

Kind regards.

Comment: Start by checking console log with firebug or something like that: 

`Error: Network Error
Stack trace:
e.exports@https://limitless-wave-headless.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.12703fd2.js:2:20182
e.exports/</d.onerror@https://limitless-wave-headless.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.12703fd2.js:2:18980`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Heroku can not generate `CLIENT_ID` with [default config](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless/blob/05720ed9ab3c2bfbc960fb7119646211d03ddaae/app.json) `"generator": "public"`.

I switched key `value` from `"value": "secret"` to `"value": "client"` - now my model loads.

Comment: I logged an issue on this https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless/issues/10